# Using jQuery Form Plugin with MVC 3 printing the controller return after submiting a form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a button like that :

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "City")" class="save button"><span class="icon-save"></span>Save</a>
```

Than I have:

```
$('.save').submitform();
$('form').ajaxForm({
    target: ".module",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == "Success") window.History.pushState(null, null, url);
    }
});
```

And my Create :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CityVM cityVM)
{
    ....
    return Content("Success");
}
```

Ok, all works fine, but doing that way, I got the string "Success" printed on page before pushState executed...

How I can Avoid that? Maybe Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$('.save').submitform();
```

You probably meant:

```
$('.save').click(function() {
    $('form').ajaxSubmit();
    return false;
});
```